# Powershell Web Server > Application Development settings

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to write a powershell scripts that activates all the features under

> Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Application Development

But for the life of me I can't find the syntax online. I've imported `servermanager` and even ran the code below to find a list of commands but can't seem to find exactly what I need.

```
Get-WindowsFeature | 
    Where-Object {$_.Installed -match “True”} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
    Write-Host
```

From the GUI here is what I'm looking for

[image]

**EDIT**

After some work with `Get-WindowsFeature Web-Server` I was able to find the `Web-App-Dev` command referenced the features I'm trying to install. However, not all of them are listed. After running the following command

```
Add-WindowsFeature Web-App-Dev
```

Only the following are installed

[image]

I've tried this "work around" however I get the same results. Does anyone know how to install every feature in the Application Development node?

```
$features = Get-WindowsFeature Web-App-Dev
$subFeatures = $features.SubFeatures

foreach($item in subFeatures)
{
    Add-WindowsFeature $item
}
```

Comment: Easiest way to work out what the names are is to call `Get-WindowsFeature *web*`. That shows a nice output listing the names of all the features, matching up with how they look in the GUI. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662312.aspx

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation. Add-WindowsFeature can be used as an alias for Install-WindowsFeature after Windows Server 2008 R2.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205467(v=wps.630).aspx

You can use the option IncludeAllSubFeature for that.

`Install-WindowsFeature Web-App-Dev -IncludeAllSubFeature`

Answer (score 0):

Found it after some investigation using `Get-WindowsFeature`:

```
Web-App-Dev
```

To install all sub features I used this loop below

```
#install Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Application Development settings
$features = Get-WindowsFeature Web-App-Dev 
$subFeatures = $features.SubFeatures -split " " 

foreach($item in $subFeatures)
{
    Add-WindowsFeature $item
}
```